# GPS application with CLCorelocation

Tags: iphone

I am developing a GPS application in which I need to track the speed of the device/iPhone.
I am using the CLCorelocation API's Locate me referral code provided by Apple. My problem is that the `LocationManager` does not update the current latitude and longitude thus I am unable to calculate the distance as well as the speed of the device/iPhone.

Any kinds of suggestions/code will be highly appreciated please suggest if I can do something with the Mapkit framework introduced in the sdk 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check out apple's [Core Location Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html).

By implementing the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation`: you can receive latitude and longitude updates from your `CLLocationManager`.

Also, since you're wanting to check the device's speed you'll probably want to set the `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` of your `CLLocationManager` to `kCLDistanceFilterNone` and `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` respectively.

If you can get yourself a copy, [Beginning iPhone Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430216261) has a chapter (#14) dedicated to using CoreLocation that I found beneficial. Lastly, although it is not focused on CoreLocation, Apple's tutorial on [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) incorporates CoreLocation data which you may find useful.

**Edit:** [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582511/iphone-corelocation-how-to-get-the-most-accurate-speed/737968#737968) specific to calculating speed.