# getting the speed at which device is moving

Tags: iphone, cllocation

I am using `CLLocation.speed` to get the speed of the device moving but I am getting 0 every time. I tried

```
speed = ([newlocation getDistanceFrom:oldlocation]/[newlocation.timeStamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldlocation.timeStamp])
```

The problem is it is giving the wrong speed once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little configuration that will help you out:

1. `CLLocationManager` will not send you an update unless the user moves outside a circle at their current location. You can control the radius of the circle (make it smaller) so you get more refined updates. See [distanceFilter](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW3).
2. `CLLocationManager` has an accuracy control, that you want to set to its finest level. See [desiredAccuracy](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18).

Your best bet is simply to continually calculate this "speed" and use a weak low-pass filter to smooth out the results.

See also this question for more information: [iPhone CoreLocation: How to get the most accurate speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582511/iphone-corelocation-how-to-get-the-most-accurate-speed).