# How do I measure the speed of another object relative to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I would like to measure the speed of another vehicle on a road (not one that the iPhone currently is in).

How would you go about measuring the speed of that other moving object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone CoreLocation: How to get the most accurate speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582511/iphone-corelocation-how-to-get-the-most-accurate-speed)

Comment: Sorry, that other question was for pure speed measurements.  It appears that you are asking how to determine the speed of another object moving relative to the iPhone.

Comment: It would be quite difficult to measure the speed of another object with an iPhone. Speed detection is usually done using the doppler effect (send a signal to the object and measure the shift in frequency of the signal that bounces off the object back to the detector), or by time-of-flight measurement of consecutive signals bounced off the object. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_camera#Methods) I don't see how either of these could be performed accurately using an iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See CoreLocation to get GPS coordinates and work out the distance between them. For instance you could take new GPS coordinates every 10 seconds and then you have time and distance. :)

Comment: while driving a car, i want to measure speed of a vehicle which is coming from an opposite direction...!! What is the soln for this problem...!

Comment: oh... i have no idea, sorry. I don't think its possible! You'd have to know how far they've moved, which means if you wanted to use the camera you would have to do some very complex mathematics, and I genuinely don't think its possible, because you would have to factor in how fast the car you are traveling in is going and counter that with the change in size of the car coming towards you. Speed cameras are extremely complex or use markings on the road which are a known distance apart to calculate speed.