# CoreLocation capturing speed

Tags: ios, swift

I am capturing location data using CLLocationManager. I am less concerned about horizontal accuracy, but I want the speed to be as accurate as possible.

Anyone know if kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers will be sufficient for my use case or do I have to use kCLLocationAccuracyBest to get the most accurate speed?

Thanks.

Comment: depends on ow you are calculating speed ?

Comment: by comparing two coordinates?

Comment: I am not calculating speed. I am reading the speed property from CLLocation (CLLocationSpeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers‍` works using cell towers (and doesn't use GPS), which doesn't give you every second's information (that's why it's good for battery), nor it uses core Motion. Without GPS or coreMotion any speed calculated won't be considered accurate

So to answer your question, no it won't give you an accurate speed, but just to be on the safe side, just jump into a car and start logging. (Though remember to turn location services off for all other apps, because sometimes other apps with better accuracy could increase your app's accuracy)

Answer (score 1):

I stuck in same issue in one of my Map Based application and i solved this way ( while traveling through Delhi Metro even i tested) and its working fine :

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //Get Current Location
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        // For getting speed
        let speed = location.speed * 2.23694
        lblSpeed.text = (location.speed<0) ? "-- \n mph" : String(format: "%d \n mph", Int(speed))
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()

}
```

**Accuracy is perfect in kCLLocationAccuracyBest**

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

Feel free to provide your feedback after using this code . Hope it solve your issue . Keep Coding

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; kCLLocationAccuracyBest is the way to go.

For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/737968/190599